# Do cookies prevent voting spam?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I'm making a simple star rating feature in PHP to my site and my general question is, do cookies prevent people from spamming multiple votes?

As far as I know I can store a cookie with javascript and PHP. What's to prevent the spammer from testing the feature, looking at what cookies are saved and then remove/add them in the spam attack script?

A sub question would be, what should I save in the cookie? That the person has already voted? What's to prevent the spammer from automatically delete all cookies before a spam attack?

So far I've got honeypot, secret code calculated by time and some other things and IP blacklisting.

I will try to stay out of captchas and recaptchas.

Comment: No, client can modify his cookies by his own, so you should not rely on it

Comment: Use session instead of cookies, session variables are stored server side while cookies are stored client side and are editable as @BogdanBurim points out. I'll write up an example for you

Comment: @Zanderwar But if you restart your browser (or just the PHP cookie), you will get a new session...

Comment: Nothing stops you from making the session and its cookie persistent.

Comment: Not sure of your setup, but if you could get a new session from just restarting your browser. Defecation would hit the oscillation

Comment: Of course, cookies will never prevent any spam.  captchas and the like are certainly useful for that.

Comment: @JuliePelletier A user can always delete their cookies. Sure, it would prevent people from just closing and reopening their browser, but if they really wanted to vote multiple times, they could just delete their cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the fact: At the worst possible case, a user may get an entire new computer to cheat your system. And there's nothing you can do about it. So no matter which client-side protections you have, they can be broken.

- Cookies are trivial to reset.
- Sessions rely on cookies, hence, trivial to reset.
- IP is easy enough to reset (or use a VPN or some other such service), moreover, mobile devices change IPs as you walk down the street.

The only real way is to authenticate your users (i.e. a login system) and only allow for authenticated users to vote.

Note that a Cookie will probably work for 95% of the cases, if you don't care the occasional cheat here and there. If cheating must be prevented at all costs, you need an authentication system.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are talking about anonymous / unauthenticated users (guests) - because if it's logged in users you can validate on server-side much more easily (e.g with Zanderwar's answer on sessions).

I'm sure you already know this rule, but in case you don't know: 
Don't do security validations on client side - you never know what browser, mobile or client the user is using. It's very easy to strip aside client side validations, spoof REST variables, encode/decode, replay transactions etc on the modern clients. So don't do security validations on clientside. Client side validation should only be used to enhance the user experience, and proper security validation should be done on server side only.

For unauthenticated, anonymous users I would restrict submissions by IP and time. E.g per IP they can only submit once per hour. You will have to record the IP and time on serverside and reject (or just update) submissions that are too frequent.

This is the simplest solution to your problem I can think of.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm talking about not logged in users. Honeypot and secret are generated with js, but that's just extra layers to make it a little bit harder, not a full protection.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent spam with cookies or sessions.  Any time you spend on this concept will be entirely wasted.

That doesn't mean that the session control can not be useful but it can not by itself prevent an experienced user from **anything**.

Voting sites usually rely either on an authentication system or the client's IP and time stamp to limit users.

Answer (score 1):

Using the browser string together with IP would make it harder but you run the risk of preventing multiple people behind the same firewall (same IP) from voting if they have very similar setup (as you could have in an office)

Aside from that login is another option but could be circumvented by creating multiple accounts.

But preventing multiple votes is always a problem unless you have an existing verified identity of the visitor.

Comment: Hello Sweden! But it would be a little bit better to combine the IP with something else to try to make sure it's the same user? Then the spammer could just switch browser but would be limited to like 5 votes before blacklisted.

Comment: That will always be the problem as long as you are talking anonymous users. A teacher on a school could have access to 20 different computers with small differences in config and could potentially fake 100 votes, but the question is more of raising the bar to a level where few enough bother to try so that the fakes do not affect the overall results to much.

Comment: In this situation with anon users, the answer is throttling - server side with ip+timestamp  (slow down submission rate) or clientside with captchas (increase their individual submission duration and prevent automation).

Answer (score 1):

It will never get a full protection without using Captcha or any other anti-bot protection as long as you give guests to use this feature.

The closest you can do, is to block by User-Agent + IP if they vote to much in a certain amount of time.

Another thing, you can do is to find a workaround using [JWT](https://jwt.io) authentication. It's a nice tool for client side session management.

Also, you can try and implement a [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). For example, you can create a unique token when loading the page of the vote, and when a user clicks on one of the stars, the system will send this token along with the vote rating.

But, again, there is no a bulletproof solution for your problem.

Comment: User agent can be spoofed very easily. IP is harder (less cost effective) to spoof, which is why I suggest IP + time.

Comment: @a20 That is what I suggested, UA + IP + time. Relying only on IP + time, is more problematic, you'll have to add another parameter for it be more precise, like UA. The chance of 5 users from the same IP to vote at the same time is higher than the chance of 5 users using the same UA from the same IP to vote at the same time. You see what I'm saying?

Comment: No, don't use user agent at all, it's not reliable (easy to spoof) and makes tracking unnecessarily complicated with 3 variables to track now.

Comment: If I would use it by itself, you are right, but it's additional to IP and time